# How do I enable right-click (control-click) context menus in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

Right Click (or control-click since I'm on a Mac) doesn't bring up the context menus for Solution or Projects.

For instance, in Visual Studio I would right click on a Solution to add a new project to the solution. I've looked all through the menu and can't find the add project command.

Also, how do I add a folder to a project? Again, this would be available from the right-click menu in VS, but I can't find it anywhere in MonoDevelop.

Control-click doesn't do anything for me in any part of MD. Not even in the text editor. Is there a setting to get it to behave the way I'm expecting it to?

Shouldn't these options also be available via the main menu also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this was a known issue and has been fixed. It was a bug in the gtk+ library. Single button mice weren't supported.

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=359734

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=346609

Still not sure why I'm seeing this bug now on my OSX 10.6.4 machine running the latest download of MonoDevelop.

Plugging in a 2-button mouse is an adequate work-around. I can right click and get the context menus I was looking for.

Comment: I'm running Version 2.4, built on 29th June

Comment: Same version here. Wonder why I've still got the bug when it was discovered in version 0.18! Oh well, at least I've got a workable system now.

Comment: The bug's in GTK (which is included with the Mono framework) not MonoDevelop itself. It was fixed, but appears to have regressed, and no-one's reported the bug yet - presumably most users use double-tap on modern macbooks. Please file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

These features are where you would expect to find them, exactly where you said. The solution context menu contains Add > Add new project and the project context menu has Add > New folder

I'm on a macbook so I get to use the old double-finger tap, rather than CTRL+Clicking all the time. Not sure why the CTRL+Click is not working for you.

EDIT:

Control-Click anywhere in the solution explorer seems to bring up a context-sensitive context menu. Control-Click whilst solution is selected brings up the solution context menu and if a project is selected, the project context menu.

Comment: Control-Click on both Solution and Project nodes in Solution tree toggles the selection of the item. Can't get the context menu.

Comment: Strange, I added more about the context menu to my answer. But if you can't display these menus at all, then it isn't going to help...

Comment: By the looks of it there are no direct shortcuts to display these dialogs.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue with MonoDevelop 2.4.  The context menus in the solution pane aren't accessible with control + click.

Answer (score 0):

Control + click doesn't work but a two finger touch brings up the context menus on my Macbook Pro.  Check your "Trackpad" settings in system preferences to see how you have secondary click setup on your mac.

Comment: I don't think he was using a laptop